# Need Help In Regular Expression - Match 6 digits after specific word

Tags: regex

I need some help in Regular Expression. Below is my input string and I need 6 digits/character after word 'CHK'

Input: `1509280928CR000000058839,19NCHK00212953`
Output: `002129`

I tried with `[CHK]{3}([0-9]{6})` but it matches along with CHK. Would you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookbehind. And also don't put `CHK` inside a character class `[]` because `[CHK]{3}` would match not only `CHK` but also `KKK`, `CCC`, etc all possible combinations.

```
(?<=CHK)[0-9]{6}
```

*OR*

Use capturing group like below and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
CHK([0-9]{6})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Positive LookBehind like as

```
(?<=CHK)(\d{6})
```

This'll check for the word `CHK` within a string and grab exact `6` digits after those words